# How to apply where condition to backbone query

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an app with Appcelerator. 
I use Backbone to get data from database.

So I have build this code to get data from database:

```
var collection = Alloy.createCollection("SocialHistoryDAO");
collection.fetch();
```

Now I want to apply a where at this collection. So I use this code:

```
collection.where(id : 5);
```

Then this code works, but now I want to apply this filter:

> "WHERE ID != 5";

It is possible to do this?

EDIT:
this is my SocialHistoryDAO model:

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        columns: {
            "ID": "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT",
            "IdOmnia": "INTEGER",
            "DateStart": "text",
            "DateEnd": "text",
            "Quantity": "decimal",
            "Code": "text",
            "CodeSystem": "text",
            "DisplayName": "text",
            "DisplayNameTarget": "text",
            "UnityMeasure": "text",
            "StateID": "INTEGER"
        },
        adapter: {
            type: "sql",
            collection_name: "SocialHistoryDAO",
            idAttribute: "ID"
        }
    },
    extendModel: function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Model;
    },
    extendCollection: function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {

            destroyAll : function(opt) {
              var db = Ti.Database.open(this.config.adapter.db_name);
              db.execute("DELETE FROM " + this.config.adapter.collection_name);
              db.close();
              this.models = [];
              if (!opt || !opt.silent) { this.trigger("reset"); }
              return this;
            }
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass the "where" to your backend query? Or filter it on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Backbone, then you're also using Underscore (or LoDash).

This can be accomplished using either:

```
var newArray = _.filter(collection.models, function(model) { return model.get('ID') != 5; });
```

or

```
var newArray = _.reject(collection.models, function(model) { return model.get('ID') == 5; });
```

Comment: I'm try your code but I have one error: State id is not defined. I have edit my post and I have insert my SocialHisotryDAO model

Comment: Edited my post. How about now?

Comment: If you are going to do this, you can use `.filter` on the collection itself: `collection.filter(function(model){})`

Comment: @KevinJantzer Right, `_.filter(collection, ...)` won't work because `collection` is probably a `Backbone.Collection` rather than an array, `collection.filter(...)` OTOH will work because [several Underscore methods are mixed into collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods).

Comment: @muistooshort – Exactly, and Backbone.Collections support underscore methods: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods

Comment: I have fix my problem with this code:
var collection = _.filter(collection.models, function(model) {

@J.Titus, can yuou edit your answer?